# Function sorting array without passing pointer

Tags: c, function, sorting

So here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  int a[4]={6,2,7,3};
  sort(a,4);
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  printf("%d",a[i]);
 }
  int sort(int a[],int n)
  {
   int i,j,temp;
   for (i=0; i< (n -1); i++)
   {
    for(j = (i+1); j < n; j++)
    {
     if (a[i]< a[j])
     {
       temp= a[i];
       a[i] = a[j];
       a[j] = temp;
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

and the output is 7632.
I thought a variable's value is never changed in main when passed to a function (unless using pointers).  It's just photocopied and operations are done.  But here the values of a[i]'s are changing in the main function.  How does that work?  I am not even returning the sorted array.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please tag your qustions properly so that you can get helpful answers? how can one identify that this is the code for C, C++ or stream?

Comment: sorry.This is my first question.I'll do that.

Comment: If you want to pass arrays around by value in C++, consider `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.  Unlike raw arrays, they copy themselves when passed by value.  Unfortunately, i don't think C has (or even can have) a real equivalent, as there's no such thing as a copy constructor.  You'd have to copy the array manually if you wanted to pass a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a pointer; arrays in function declarations decay to a pointer to their first element.

Comment: and a definition of _array decay_ : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Comment: So you mean,if I try to pass an array,it automatically becomes a pointer?

Comment: And does it happen for any other things, or just arrays?

Comment: @user2316393 yes.  If you want to actually pass an array by value, you need to wrap it in a `struct`.  It's one of the more confusing historical accidents in C. See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html

Comment: @user2316393 Functions decay to function pointers, but not in function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sort(int a[],int n)
{
    ...
}
```

`a` is a pointer even though you used `[]`. You cannot pass arrays in C or C++, instead a pointer to the first element is passed.

Comment: So you mean,if I try to pass an array,it automatically becomes a pointer?

Comment: @user2316393: Yep.  Arrays "decay" to pointers automatically.  At the drop of a hat, really.  :P  C-style arrays are rather bare-bones; they're basically just a block of contiguous, properly aligned, element-sized storage bins, and don't even carry info about how many bins.  That makes copying much harder to do reliably.  There are two fixes for that: make arrays include their length (turning them more into something like structs), or forget copying entirely and pass them around as pointers.  C chose the latter.